# Error deploying play framework application on heroku

Tags: heroku, deployment, playframework-2.0

I am trying to deploy my play framework app on heroku using commands from this [link](http://www.jamesward.com/2012/02/21/play-framework-2-with-scala-anorm-json-coffeescript-jquery-heroku)

every command works fine but on entering url of my heroku app on browser it gives error

```
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
```

and my logs

```
     $ heroku logs
←[36m2014-03-28T19:07:14.844022+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at com.jolbox.bonecp.Bon
eCP.<init>(BoneCP.java:416)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:07:14.844084+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at com.jolbox.bonecp.Bon
eCPDataSource.getConnection(BoneCPDataSource.java:120)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:07:14.844173+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at play.api.db.BoneCPPlu
gin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(DB.scala:245)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:07:14.844274+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   ... 22 more
←[36m2014-03-28T19:07:14.843293+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at org.sqlite.JDBC.conne
ct(JDBC.java:87)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:07:14.842752+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at play.core.server.Nett
yServer$.main(NettyServer.scala:274)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:07:14.843069+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Caused by: java.sql.SQLExc
eption: invalid database address: jdbc:postgresql://ec2-107-22-163-140.compute-1
.amazonaws.com:5432/d6s749rg71m651
←[36m2014-03-28T19:07:14.842849+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at play.core.server.Nett
yServer.main(NettyServer.scala)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:07:14.842607+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at scala.Option.map(Opti
on.scala:145)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:07:14.843293+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at org.sqlite.JDBC.creat
eConnection(JDBC.java:110)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:07:14.843614+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at java.sql.DriverManage
r.getConnection(DriverManager.java:620)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:07:14.843892+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at com.jolbox.bonecp.Bon
eCP.obtainRawInternalConnection(BoneCP.java:363)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:07:14.843736+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at java.sql.DriverManage
r.getConnection(DriverManager.java:200)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:07:16.130352+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Process exited with sta
tus 255
←[36m2014-03-28T19:07:16.141752+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from star
ting to crashed
←[33m2014-03-28T19:07:44.845404+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=error code=H10 desc
="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=protected-anchorage-4936.herokuapp.com req
uest_id=7b22fdb3-3fc5-49ee-b1bb-cac8b2807bf2 fwd="14.96.131.39" dyno= connect= s
ervice= status=503 bytes=
←[32m2014-03-28T19:16:15+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]:←[0m Slug compilation start
ed
←[32m2014-03-28T19:17:25+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]:←[0m Slug compilation finis
hed
←[35m2014-03-28T19:17:25.404502+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Deploy eff2544 by singh_a
kash@outlook.com
←[35m2014-03-28T19:17:25.404581+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Release v19 created by si
ngh_akash@outlook.com
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:25.898367+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from cras
hed to starting
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:32.749170+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Starting process with c
ommand `target/universal/stage/bin/shoplist  -Dhttp.port=${PORT} -DapplyEvolutio
ns.default=true -Ddb.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver -Ddb.default.url=${DAT
ABASE_URL}`
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:34.024991+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTION
S:  -Djava.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly=true
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:34.615701+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Play server process ID is
2
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:35.776341+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m DEBUG - JDBC URL = jdbc:po
stgresql://ec2-107-22-163-140.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d6s749rg71m651, Usern
ame = wgvvlxnnjghjvl, partitions = 1, max (per partition) = 30, min (per partiti
on) = 5, idle max age = 10 min, idle test period = 1 min, strategy = DEFAULT
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:36.042444+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m INFO  - database [default]
 connected at jdbc:postgresql://ec2-107-22-163-140.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/
d6s749rg71m651
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:36.623938+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m DEBUG - select id, hash, a
pply_script, revert_script, state, last_problem from play_evolutions where state
 like 'applying_%'
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:36.676247+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m @6hl3hpiok: Database 'defa
ult' is in an inconsistent state!
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:36.676489+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at play.api.db.evolution
s.Evolutions$.checkEvolutionsState(Evolutions.scala:193)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:36.673218+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m ERROR - ERROR: syntax erro
r at or near "auto_increment"
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:36.673218+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Position: 57 [ERROR:0, S
QLSTATE:42601]
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:36.676578+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at play.api.db.evolution
s.Evolutions$$anonfun$evolutionScript$2.apply(Evolutions.scala:311)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:36.676489+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at play.api.db.evolution
s.Evolutions$.databaseEvolutions(Evolutions.scala:348)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:36.676489+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at play.api.db.evolution
s.Evolutions$$anonfun$evolutionScript$2.apply(Evolutions.scala:313)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:36.676578+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at scala.Option.map(Opti
on.scala:145)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:36.676170+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Oops, cannot start the ser
ver.
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:36.676791+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at play.api.db.evolution
s.Evolutions$.evolutionScript(Evolutions.scala:311)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:36.677033+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at play.api.Play$.start(
Play.scala:87)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:36.676791+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at play.api.db.evolution

s.EvolutionsPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(Evolutions.scala:459)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:36.676791+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at scala.collection.immu
table.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:36.676791+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at play.api.db.evolution
s.EvolutionsPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(Evolutions.s
cala:462)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:36.676791+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at play.api.db.evolution
s.EvolutionsPlugin.onStart(Evolutions.scala:459)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:36.676791+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at play.api.Play$$anonfu
n$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:88)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:36.676791+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at play.api.db.evolution
s.EvolutionsPlugin.withLock(Evolutions.scala:507)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:36.676791+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at play.api.db.evolution
s.EvolutionsPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(Evolutions.scala:461)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:36.677033+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at play.core.StaticAppli
cation.<init>(ApplicationProvider.scala:52)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:36.676791+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at play.api.Play$$anonfu
n$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:88)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:36.677033+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at play.api.Play$$anonfu
n$start$1.apply$mcV$sp(Play.scala:88)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:36.677033+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at play.api.Play$$anonfu
n$start$1.apply(Play.scala:88)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:36.677301+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at play.core.server.Nett
yServer$.main(NettyServer.scala:274)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:36.677301+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at play.core.ser
ver.NettyServer.main(NettyServer.scala)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:36.677301+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at play.core.server.Nett
yServer$$anonfun$main$3.apply(NettyServer.scala:279)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:36.677301+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at scala.Option.map(Opti
on.scala:145)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:36.676791+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at scala.collection.immu
table.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:36.677301+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at play.core.server.Nett
yServer$$anonfun$main$3.apply(NettyServer.scala:274)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:36.677033+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at play.api.Play$$anonfu
n$start$1.apply(Play.scala:88)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:36.677033+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at play.utils.Threads$.w
ithContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:18)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:36.677301+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at play.core.server.Nett
yServer$.createServer(NettyServer.scala:243)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:37.812494+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Process exited with sta
tus 255
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:37.819425+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from star
ting to crashed
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:37.819966+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from cras
hed to starting
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:44.692801+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Starting process with c
ommand `target/universal/stage/bin/shoplist  -Dhttp.port=${PORT} -DapplyEvolutio
ns.default=true -Ddb.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver -Ddb.default.url=${DAT
ABASE_URL}`
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:45.897215+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTION
S:  -Djava.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly=true
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:46.781826+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Play server process ID is
2
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:48.011081+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m DEBUG - JDBC URL = jdbc:po
stgresql://ec2-107-22-163-140.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d6s749rg71m651, Usern
ame = wgvvlxnnjghjvl, partitions = 1, max (per partition) = 30, min (per partiti
on) = 5, idle max age = 10 min, idle test period = 1 min, strategy = DEFAULT
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:48.413328+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m INFO  - database [default]
 connected at jdbc:postgresql://ec2-107-22-163-140.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/
d6s749rg71m651
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:49.031934+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Position: 57 [ERROR:0, S
QLSTATE:42601]
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:49.035408+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m @6hl3i0b63: Database 'defa
ult' is in an inconsistent state!
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:49.014161+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m DEBUG - select id, hash, a
pply_script, revert_script, state, last_problem from play_evolutions where state
 like 'applying_%'
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:49.031934+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m ERROR - ERROR: syntax erro
r at or near "auto_increment"
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:49.035408+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Oops, cannot start the ser
ver.
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:49.035739+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at play.api.db.evolution
s.Evolutions$$anonfun$evolutionScript$2.apply(Evolutions.scala:311)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:49.036232+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at play.api.db.evolution
s.Evolutions$.evolutionScript(Evolutions.scala:311)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:49.035739+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at play.api.db.evolution
s.Evolutions$.checkEvolutionsState(Evolutions.scala:193)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:49.036232+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at play.api.db.evolution
s.EvolutionsPlugin.withLock(Evolutions.scala:507)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:49.036232+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at play.api.db.evolution
s.EvolutionsPlugin.onStart(Evolutions.scala:459)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:49.036232+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at play.api.db.evolution
s.EvolutionsPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(Evolutions.scala:461)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:49.035739+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at play.api.db.evolution
s.Evolutions$.databaseEvolutions(Evolutions.scala:348)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:49.035739+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at play.api.db.evolution
s.Evolutions$$anonfun$evolutionScript$2.apply(Evolutions.scala:313)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:49.035739+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at scala.Option.map(Opti
on.scala:145)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:49.036232+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at play.api.db.evolution
s.EvolutionsPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(Evolutions.s
cala:462)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:49.036575+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at play.api.Play$$anonfu
n$start$1.apply$mcV$sp(Play.scala:88)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:49.036232+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at scala.collection.immu
table.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:49.036575+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at play.api.Play$$anonfu
n$start$1.apply(Play.scala:88)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:49.036232+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at play.api.Play$$anonfu
n$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:88)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:49.036575+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at play.api.Play$$anonfu
n$start$1.apply(Play.scala:88)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:49.036232+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at play.api.db.evolution
s.EvolutionsPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(Evolutions.scala:459)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:49.036232+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at scala.collection.immu
table.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:49.036232+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at play.api.Play$$anonfu
n$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:88)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:49.036575+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at play.utils.Threads$.w
ithContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:18)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:49.036575+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at play.api.Play$.start(
Play.scala:87)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:49.036988+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at play.core.server.Nett
yServer$.createServer(NettyServer.scala:243)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:49.036988+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at play.core.server.Nett
yServer$.main(NettyServer.scala:274)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:49.036988+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at play.core.StaticAppli
cation.<init>(ApplicationProvider.scala:52)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:49.036988+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at play.core.server.Nett
yServer$$anonfun$main$3.apply(NettyServer.scala:279)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:49.036988+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at play.core.server.Nett
yServer$$anonfun$main$3.apply(NettyServer.scala:274)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:49.036988+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at play.core.server.Nett
yServer.main(NettyServer.scala)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:49.036988+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at scala.Option.map(Opti
on.scala:145)
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:50.634268+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from star
ting to crashed
←[36m2014-03-28T19:17:50.622291+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Process exited with sta
tus 255
←[33m2014-03-28T19:18:03.883698+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=error code=H10 desc
="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=protected-anchorage-4936.herokuapp.com req
uest_id=a54ed420-3fb9-444d-8fb1-b218b8c51284 fwd="14.96.131.39" dyno= connect= s
ervice= status=503 bytes=
```

I am new to heroku and not able to understand what the problem is
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `play stage` and then look in the `target/universal/stage/bin` directory to see what the start script is named.  Then update your `Procfile` and repush to Heroku.

Comment: on doing play stage it shows
"Error occurred during initialization of VM
Incompatible minimum and maximum heap sizes specified"                   and i cant find any directory named /universal/stage/bin inside my target folder

Comment: Do you have JAVA_OPTS or SBT_OPTS environment variables?  What OS are you on?  Another option is to run: `heroku run bash` and then do `ls target/universal/stage/bin` to see what the start script is named.

Comment: no i dint set any environment variable,i am using windows 8.1          on running heroku run bash it shows
"Running `bash` attached to terminal... up, run.3850
~ $ ls target/universal/stage/bin
ls target/universal/stage/bin
shoplist  shoplist.bat"                                              but my project name is ShopList,s and l in caps                     does the case of character affects?                                 what path should i set for JAVA_OPTS?                                       i dint set any environment variable uptill now.

Comment: Your `Procfile` needs to contain the `target/universal/stage/bin/shoplist` path.

Comment: ok i have changed my Procfile but its shows same application error in browser and no such directory error is now removed from my logs           i have pasted my new logs above

Comment: when i am doing git push heroku master it shows size of 102.3MB

Comment: Now the error is that it can't connect to the DB.  You'll need to make sure your db config is correct.

Comment: it again giving the error                                                " invalid database address: jdbc:postgresql://ec2-107-22-163-140.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d6s749rg71m651"                           ive checked my database url i dont know what to do

Comment: Does it work locally with that db url?  Are you using the correct db url format for the Play?

Comment: i was using mysql in the past but switched to postgre now but its giving error running locally  when trying to save data through forms in my project running in browser                                         [IllegalStateException: JSR-303 validated property 'lastName' does not have a corresponding accessor for data binding - check your DataBinder's configuration (bean property versus direct field access)]                                                              my db url is db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/mydb"

Comment: Try this form: `postgres://hostfoo.com:1234/dbname`

Comment: when i am entering localhost:9000 in browser it shows configuration error in line db.default.url="postgres://hostfoo.com:1234/dbname"

Comment: [error] c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook - Failed to obtain initial connection Sleeping for 0ms and trying again. Attempts
 left: 0. Exception: null.Message:invalid database address: postgres://hostfoo.com:1234/dbname                                     it shows in my powershell while entering localhost:9000 in browser

Comment: Are you using Heroku Postgres?  If so you should set  `db.default.url=${DATABASE_URL}` and then locally set and env variable named `DATABASE_URL` to the value of what you see that set to when you run `heroku config`.

Comment: i am using posgresql9.3.4 downloaded from this link                         http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload#windows                                               do i have to download a diffrent heroku postgre to use database on heroku?if so then does my app run locally with that

Comment: You can do it that way if you want.  But either way I'd set a `DATABASE_URL` config param on Heroku.  This thread might also help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22712611/cannot-connect-to-remote-heroku-postgres-database-using-play-framework-2-2-2/2271526

Comment: same error,in my logs it first shows invalid database url then it shows connected to default server then inconsistent database                 i am more confused now, i had set DATABASE_URL environment variable also                                                                   pasted my new logs above

Comment: do i have to set environment variable shown in "heroku config"?              i have set only DATABASE_URL environment variable.

Comment: my project is working fine locally with these settings                      db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydbname"
db.default.user=postgres
db.default.password=password

Comment: when i changed my settings to the thread u showed me                                                                                                   it shows configuration error in browser

Comment: Looks like it connected this time.  Now you just need to apply the evolutions.  Try to set `-DapplyEvolutions.default=true` on your Heroku app.  Either via `JAVA_OPTS` config param or in the `Procfile`.

Comment: and my console output             DEBUG - JDBC URL=postgres:\\wgvvlxnnjghjvl:okEBIYECK9y_RBVkBwDMD8dg1H@ec2-107-22-163-140.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432\
d6s749rg71m651, Username = null, partitions = 1, max (per partition) = 30, min (per partition) = 5, idle max age = 10 mi
n, idle test period = 1 min, strategy = DEFAULT
WARN  - JDBC username was not set in config!
WARN  - JDBC password was not set in config!
ERROR - Failed to obtain initial connection Sleeping for 0ms and trying again. Attempts left: 0. Exception: null.Message:invaliddatabaseaddress:postgres:

Comment: Given that info here is what your `Procfile` should contain: `web: target/universal/stage/bin/shoplist -Dhttp.port=${PORT} -Ddb.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://ec2-107-22-163-140.compu‌​te-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d6s749rg71m651" -Ddb.default.user=wgvvlxnnjghjvl -Ddb.default.password=okEBIYECK9y_RBVkBwDMD8dg1H -DapplyEvolutions.default=true`

Comment: it says "Push failed: cannot parse Procfile."

Comment: Make sure that is all on one line.

Comment: its on one line checked it and pushed it again

Comment: thanks for the help @James                                                                  its working on heroku by disabling the evolution plugin in conf file and by changing procfile to   " web: target/universal/stage/bin/shoplist -Dhttp.port=${PORT} -DapplyEvolutions.default=true"                                            on doing heroku open the browser shows my project but i am unable to save anything in database,the database is not created, browser shows "oops an error occured" while doing any database related tasks      trying to figure out this problem now

Comment: when i am disabling evolution by removing `#` from `evolutionplugin=disabled` it works fine                                      how can i create my database without evolution in heroku?

Comment: Why are you disabling the evolutions plugin?

Comment: because its not working without it,means if i am enabling it my app is crashing,see my logs it says `syntax error at or near auto_increment`

Comment: Your evolutions were not created for MySQL.  You should recreate them locally with a MySQL configured DB.

Comment: when i was using mysql i created db with evolution then i swithed to postgresql and created  database again locally by evolution with this configuration  `db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbname"
db.default.user="postgres"
db.default.password="password"` in my conf file

Comment: then i changed my conf file accoding to the thread u showed me given below `db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url="postgres://postgres:password@localhost:5432/dbname"
db.default.url=${?DATABASE_URL}`                                          its not running locally but running on heroku as i told u           so should i recreate them locally in mysql again?

Comment: Ah, I got lost there.  Should have said that you need to create your evolutions for the db that you are trying to apply them against.  So if you are using Postgres on Heroku and trying to apply your evolutions there then the evolutions need to have been created for Postgres.  That might mean deleting them, recreating them, getting the new ones into Git, and re-pushing.

Comment: sorry for replying late, having some problem recreating evolution,               my evolution is created but some tables are not creating with it, i have posted this question      `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22793097/recreating-evolution-for-postgresql`but `thank u so much for the help` my project is partially working

Answer (score 1):

The error `target/start: No such file or directory` hints that heroku thinks your app is a play 2.1 app when it really is a play 2.2 app.

Read about the correct procfile for Play 2.2 here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/play-support

Comment: i have changed my procfile but still getting the same error

Comment: if you changed your Procfile to try to run 'target/universal/stage/bin/yourapp' and it still fails with the old message about 'target/start' then you must have failed to actually push the new Procfile to heroku somehow.

Comment: ok now i have done everything again, git init,git add .,git commit -m "init",then created a new app and pushed it ,but same error  target/universal/stage/bin/myappname: No such file or directory

Comment: You are not supposed to have 'myappname' in Procfile but replace it with the name you gave your app when you created it.

Comment: i am replacing 'myappname' with the name that i had given to my app during its creation

Comment: Now there is something wrong with the database connection, read the log output carefully and you should find the warning (you should probably edit the logs and be a bit more careful about posting them online since they do contain your db password and username).

Comment: i was using mysql in the past now swithed to postgresql,changed my conf file ,my project is compiling fine locally but giving invalid database address error in my logs while deploying to heroku,i am really confused now

Comment: ok now i am getting error running locally                                            [PersistenceException: Query threw SQLException:ERROR: column t0.email does not exist Position: 8 Bind values:[] Query was: select t0.email as c0, t0.password as c1, t0.first_name as c2, t0.last_name as c3 from user t0 where t0.email is null and t0.password is null ]     its not giving any compile time error but shows this on browser while doing database actions

Comment: It says there is no column email in the table you are trying to read.

Comment: i am trying to create my database through evolution but when i click to apply this script button in browser it says "error at or near user" my user table is                                                            create table user (
email                     varchar(255) not null,
password                  varchar(255),
first_name                varchar(255),
last_name                 varchar(255),
constraint pk_user primary key (email))
;

Comment: In think in Postgres you can't have a table named `user`.

Comment: ya user is a keyword in postgres so its was giving problem creating that table,changed my User model name and it worked fine