# Cannot connect to remote Heroku Postgres database using Play Framework 2.2.2

Tags: database, postgresql, heroku, playframework

I have an Heroku account and I created an app and an Heroku-Postgres database.
I already commited the app to the Heroku cloud, but I cannot access to the DB that I created.

I'm using play, and when i connect my project in my local DB, the application.conf configurations are:

```
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres"
db.default.user=postgres
db.default.password=password
```

And run my server locally and it works fine.

Before I upload my app to Heroku I changed this file to access my Heroku-Postgres DB:

db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://url:5432/database_name?user=name&password=pass&ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory"

The user and password fields are no longer needed. I've already created a file in the root of my project named "Procfile" that has:

```
web: target/universal/stage/bin/playsense -Dhttp.port=${PORT} -DapplyEvolutions.default=true -Ddb.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver -Ddb.default.url=${DATABASE_URL}
```

I discovered this on the documentation. I don't understand why it doesn't connect to my DB.
I used pgAdminIII with the DB credentials and it works fine.

It's something missing/wrong and I don't know what.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to unset the `db.default.user` and `db.default.password` config params when running on Heroku.  But I'm not sure of an easy way to do that.  So what I usually do is to not set them in the `conf/application.conf` and instead I do something like:

```
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url="postgres://postgres:password@localhost:5432/postgres"
db.default.url=${?DATABASE_URL}
#db.default.user=postgres
#db.default.password=password
```

That provides a default `db.default.url` but overrides it with the `DATABASE_URL` env var if it is set.

Comment: How do i debug this on Heroku, to see if the it's nothing wrong with my code. Even with this configurations, it's not accessing my DB. Maybe it's something else. Locally, everything works, running play on debug mode on my computer and accessing my pgAdmin local DB.

Comment: Use `heroku logs` to see any logged errors with your app on Heroku.